# In which systems fundamental theorem of arithmetic fails?

Tags: number-theory, terminology, algebraic-number-theory

I'm a beginner in Number Theory and I was searching for the answer to this question.

$Question$

We know that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic holds for positive integers but it fails for algebraic integers. So my questions is:

What is the "word/ terminology " used for all the possible 'systems' in which the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic(FTA) fails?

Comment: Well, the rings for which it *holds* are called [Unique Factorization Domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).

Comment: @lulu yeah I read about them but what about where it doesn't hold, is there any specific term for such systems?

Comment: Non unique factorization domains?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  Non unique factorization domains are the generic case, you should never assume unique factorization holds in a ring.  The integers are quite misleading, in this instance.

Comment: @DavidP I don't know sir I searched quite a lot to find any specific term but didn't get it, if you saw something like this written in any texts then please share

Comment: The ring of algebraic integers in a finite extension of Q is a Dedekind domain, and there's a straightforward criterion for when a Dedekind domain has unique factorization of elements.

Comment: Since the terminology of *unique factorization domain* is completely standard, everyone would understand if you simply negated that terminology, **even if** the negated version of that terminology was not found in any texts... although, motivated by the comment of @DustanLevenstein regarding Dedekind domains, you should nonetheless also make sure you clearly express what kind of 'systems' you are restricting your terminology too.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm a beginner sir, forgive me if I mistype any wrong info related to the topic, here I'm concerned about all possible systems where the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic (FTA) doesn't hold. let me edit the question

Comment: "factorial" (domain/ring/monoid) is a synonym for "unique factorization" and its negation "nonfactorial" is not uncommon.

Comment: @BillDubuque So can I use "nonfactorial systems" as a term? (I'm writing a research paper and recently I thought about studying systems where FTA doesn't hold.)

Comment: "All possible systems" is impossibly broad, and perhaps even meaningless. What is a "system"?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yeah it seems meaningless but here system can be taken as a field extension of Q or maybe more than that. (Sorry I don't have much deep knowledge about Algebraic number theory but will think about it later after studying some standard topics).

Comment: Why not just say "field extensions of Q which are not UFDs" or "field extensions of Q that do not have the unique factorisation property"? (Lang tried to introduce the term "factorial ring" as a nicer alternative to "UFD", but, pace @BillDubuque, I don't think his proposal took on.)

Comment: @RobArthan Sir if you don't mind can we talk in a discussion chat separately?

Comment: Related: Heegner numbers